# polymer and jade with attributtes

Tags: json, pug, polymer

I have my polymer element  as this:
    polymer-element(attributes='device' name='html-404')

when I make the declaration of attributes in jade:

```
  link(rel='import', href='src/html-404.html')
  section
    html-404(device ='#{device}')
```

I got my HTML in this way:

```
'<html-404 device="[Object Object]">'
```

and I cant use the data in my code.

Device

{
  "device": {
      "marca" : "samsung",
      "device" : "telefono"
    }
}

Comment: What is `device` expected to be?

Comment: device is a json object a var that I need to use template to make databinding, and use it in my element polymer like {{device.brand}}

Answer (score 0):

Try stringifying it as JSON:

```
html-404(device=JSON.stringify(device))
```

Comment: thanks but this is not working <html-404 device="{marca:samsung,device:telefono}"></bbva-404>